# tensorflow : conv2d_transpose : Matching desired output dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

How can I force certain dimensionality of the output of the `conv2d_transpose` layer ? My problem is that I use it for upsampling and I want to match the dimensionality of my labels and the output of the `NN`, for example if I have a feature map as `Bx25x40xC` how can I make it `Bx100x160xC` (i.e. upsample exactly 4x times)?
It seems like dimensions of the output can be calculated using

```
h = ((h_in - 1) * stride_h) + kernel_h - 2 * pad_h
w = ((w_in - 1) * stride_w) + kernel_w - 2 * pad_w
```

one can manipulate strides and kernels, but padding is controlled by `'same'/'valid'` algorithms which, to my understanding, means they are pretty much uncontrollable, so is the resulting output size. For comparison, in caffe, one can at least force the padding in attempt to match the desired output explicitly.

Comment: There isn't enough flexibility in TensorFlow's conv operators right now to enable this. There's been internal interest in improving this too, so could you file a github issue with your feature request and that will help us prioritize fixing it?